# Binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt32' and 'UInt'

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to programming in Swift and I am trying to develop a simple game in the hopes that it will increase my exposure to the language syntax and logic. Currently I have a problem in Swift which is stating "Binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt32' and 'UInt'" and I do not know how to approach this problem as I am a newbie to the language. Can someone show me how to approach this problem and why is the problem being caused in the first place?

For reference purposes I have included a method that causes the problem and the problem name.

```
   func randomFloatBetween(_ smallNumber: CGFloat, and bigNumber: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let diff: CGFloat = bigNumber - smallNumber
        return ((CGFloat(arc4random() % (UInt(RAND_MAX) + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber
    }
```

Comment: You should not be using `arc4Random`. Update to Swift 4.2 and use the numeric range `random` method.

Comment: I am currently using the latest version of Swift (version 4.2) and the compiler is printing a message which says "rand() is available in Swift". Why might this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to coerce `RAND_MAX` to `UInt32` instead of `UInt` and coerce `RAND_MAX` to `CGFLoat`:

```
func randomFloatBetween(_ smallNumber: CGFloat, and bigNumber: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let diff = bigNumber - smallNumber
    return CGFloat(arc4random() % (UInt32(RAND_MAX) + 1)) / CGFloat(RAND_MAX) * diff + smallNumber
}
```

---

```
randomFloatBetween(1, and: 2)  // 1.71263541686937
```

You can also extend `ClosedRange` constraining `Bound` to `BinaryFloatingPoint`:

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound: BinaryFloatingPoint, Bound.RawSignificand: FixedWidthInteger {
    var random: Bound { return .random(in: self) }
}
```

---

```
let random1: CGFloat = (1.0...2.0).random    // 1.964941881451907

let random2: Float = (1.0...2.0).random    // 1.426581

let random3: Double = (1.0...2.0).random    // 1.706499406585947
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand the reason behind why the code was unavailable to compile. The data types did not match.

Comment: you are welcome